# How to check if a download is complete using PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I can create dynamic download link with expire time using PHP. But I want to delete the link when the user completed the download. Is there any way to know when the user has completed the download with PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: Not reliably using JavaScript AFAIK. The best thing you can do is to automatically delete the file after N days, hours, you choose. That's why all sites (that *do* have something like that) say like "Dear user your download link will be available for *N time*."

Comment: Do you want to delete the link to the file or the linked file?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035294/showing-download-progress-while-downloading-a-file-using-php-and-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245347/download-status-with-php-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use a php page to process the users request to download, which will trigger it to delete it a short time afterwards?

Comment: `short time` is not the same in a town with fast internet connection and in some desolated village on a mobile connection

Comment: Based on the file size you could make it take into account a dial up connection and delete the file a long time after, or 24 hours after requested.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically handled client side.

You can find a very nice answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168965/1174052).

The way I handle that is using jQuery. In JavaScript I launch downloads asynchronously and the calling function allows to call a callback function. In this callback function you can empty the div corresponding to your download link and potentially send a message to the server.

```
    // have a div in your document to call this JavaScript script
    // first get the file in local memory
    var file = "myfile.csv";
    $.get(file, function(data){
        // everything here will be done only when the download is finished
        // in particular you want the user to be able to get the file using 
         mydoc.execCommand("saveAs",true,".txt");

        // as described 
        // here: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?12509-how-to-pop-up-Save-As-Window

        // you can also change the div containing the link/button activating the download 
        // and possibly send the server a download OK signal
```

});

Comment: How can you reliably say "Yes, the file has been successfully downloaded by the client." ?

Comment: That is the job of the asynchronous download function. It will call the callback function only when the download is complete

Comment: Can you please point to some documentation that explains the use of a successful *download callback*?